# I have an array of links, and would like to parse each link, what's the most efficient way of examining each with Nokogiri? - Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nokogiri

So say I have an array that looks like this:

```
links = [['May 1', 'Link A', 'www.linka.com'], ['May 2', 'Link B', 'www.linkb.com']]
```

What I would like to do with Nokogiri is go to each link and return specific text (per an xpath I have) on each page.

I know I can do something like:

```
links.each do |x|
   doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(x[2]))
end
```

Then traverse each `doc` within that `each` loop. But, given that my array might have 700 items in it...this seems like it will be very inefficient. With all sorts of nested loops and such.

Is there a more efficient way to attack this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: You want to be careful with using `#open` the way Nokogiri's documentation tells you to, too.  It does not clean up the files it creates, which can cause your server to run out of disk space doing things like this. I personally fetch the page into memory with RestClient, then parse it with Nokogiri.

Comment: @d11wtq So you fetch it, and store it in say an array, and then parse the array with Nokogiri?

Comment: @beck03076 What example do you have for multi-threading?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at something like **Typhoeus** or **EM-HTTP-Request** to parallelize your HTTP requests.

Processing the pages themselves with Nokogiri will be a CPU-bound task, so multithreading that task won't give you much (or any) speedup.

Your biggest slowdown will come from the HTTP requests, so making those execute in parallel will provide the biggest speedup.

**Typhoeus**:
https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus

**EM-HTTP-Request**:
https://github.com/igrigorik/em-http-request

Comment: I think you mean *Typhoeus*, not Typotheus. Nice typo, though.